# R: Can we Sum an vector with condition?

Tags: r, function

Is it possible for us to use sum all the elements having even index in R vector without going through iterating through all the elements ? such as sum(vectorx[i*2], which i in (1:5))

Answer (score 1):

Multiply the vector by `c(0, 1)` and then add the elements. Due to vector recycling, the elements with odd indices will be multiplied by `0` and the ones in even indices will be multiplied by `1`

```
 x = 1:10
sum(x * c(0, 1))
#[1] 30
```

Comment: Throws a warning though with vectors of uneven length.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this

```
set.seed(1234)
i <- sample(5)
i
#[1] 4 5 2 3 1
```

1) Use recycling method

```
sum(i[c(FALSE, TRUE)])
#[1] 8
```

2) Create a sequence of alternating index to subset

```
sum(i[seq(2, length(i), 2)])
```

3) Use modulo division

```
sum(i[seq_along(i) %% 2 == 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `seq.int`

```
x <- 1:10
sum(x[seq.int(2, length(x), 2)])
```